# how to get the UTF8 binary value of a NSString

Tags: iphone, ios, utf-8, nsstring, binary-data

So I am wanting to send a request to a server I am working with, it requieres the binary value of a (utf-8 formatted nsstring) if there is such a thing, I have read that NSStrings are unicode formatted...

basically the idea is to send the value of the nsstring to the server without the added 3 byte header that UTF8 applies to the front of a string. This is because the server knows I will be sending it UTF8 formatted string in binary format so to save unnessacery formatting values that could bloat my requests I would like to try and do it this way.

dose any one have any ideas on how I might achieve this? I'm currently reading up about NSStrings on the apple docs, but there is so much to read and process I'm hoping someone can provide me some insight.

I don't have any code to show for this atm because I'm only in the planning and understanding phase of this, and to move forward I need to understand how this might be done so I can start coding it :)

any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

NSString has a UTF8String method.  It returns chars and chars are bytes. Does that work?

```
-(const char *)UTF8String
```

Return Value:
A null-terminated UTF8 representation of the receiver.

more info on it here.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html

Comment: cool, I will read more into this.. I have been thinking down the same line its more I need to understand what I have to work with then go have a chat to the guy whos working with the db engine.. but I'm thinking its going to be good enough. just so much reeaaaddding! thanks for your reply I'll keep this open for a couple more hours to see if i get any other responses thanks again

Comment: i Just found this method in the link you sent me **getBytes:maxLength:usedLength:encoding:options:range:remainingRange:** his looks like something I might be able to use...